# Passing objects to Junit Test in web application

Tags: java, junit

How can I pass an object to JUnit test given the fact that the object can not be created in the JUnit class using the @Parameters?

The fact is that the object is created dynamically by a service outside of the web application and I want to test that it's valid before creating the heavy resources required in the remaining process (that use the object).

Edit:

```
public void doService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    MyObject myObject = ... //Get Object from external service

    JUnitCore runner = ... //Create runner
    runner.run(MyTestCase.class); //throws exception when objet is not valid

    ...//Create the heavy resources and delegate to custom process

}
```

MyTestCase:

```
public class MyTestCase{
    @Test
    public void testValidObject(){
        MyObject myObject = ...//How to retrieve MyObject here?
    }
}
```

Comment: I have shared what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object requires some form of validation anyway you could store a list of validators that receive myObject. Your test would look something like:

```
public class MyTestCase{
    @Test
    public void testValidObject(){
        Service service = new Service();
        service.addValidator(new IMyObjectValidator() {
                  boolean validate(MyObject myObject) {
                    // some assertions here
                    return true; 
                  }
               });

        service.doService(mockRequest, mockResponse);

        // some final assertions here
    }
}
```

You would need an interface IMyObjectValidator:

```
interface IMyObjectValidator {
   boolean validate(MyObject myObject);
}
```

And your doService method would need to store and call the validators after the object's creation. This is actually the observer pattern, which in another form might also serve your purpose.

Comment: If I get it correctly, by "Service.doServer" you mean "Service.doService"? Which means that MyTestCase is the one that should call the doService method and not be called by doService? 

Well, i will need to find a way to create mockRequest and mockResponse... The fact is that the object is created with a lot of parameters that are passed through the HttpServletRequest (I pass it to the service), and creating a mock one will not be easy... There are a lot of parameters that are linked

Comment: Yes, I mean doService instead of doServer (I've changed it).

Comment: As a rule production code should never contain nor call testing code. Creating a mockRequest and mockResponse is not really that difficult using a mocking framework, but that was not the question (there is plenty of help for that out there). Instead you can also extract a method out of doService that does not use these two parameters, but instead uses simpler, more readable and testable datatypes. For example: doService uses a request parameter with the name "firstName", so let doService get that firstName into a string and call a method that has a firstName parameter. Then test that method.

Comment: Ok. I did not intend to deploy JUnit class in production, but rather in our test server. 

I wanted to use them in real case because my above servlet is called by another service that send a huge number of parameters. The MyObject returned by the external service is the result of many processes on the service's side using those parameters. I don't know the processes logic, but I know what to expect for various method in the returned MyObject. I didn't want to create mock parameters since there are so many of them. Currently they are provided by another external service.

Comment: Integration tests as opposed to unit tests are always a lot of work to set up properly and require a lot of maintenance. There is not much that can be done about it. Anyway, the observer pattern should help you with your question. I would appreciate an acceptance of my answer or an upvote for the effort.